# Concave envelope: equivalent definitions

Tags: convex-optimization, envelope

Let $f: X\to \mathbb{R}$ be bounded. Consider the following definitions:

**Definition 1:** $f^{*}(x)=\inf\{h(x): h\in \mathbb{R}^{X} \;\;\text{affine and}\;\; h\ge f\}$.

**Definition 2:** $f^{**}(x)=\inf\{h(x): h\in \mathbb{R}^{X} \;\;\text{affine, continuous and}\;\; h\ge f\}$.

**Definition 3:** $f^{***}(x)=\min\{h(x): h\in \mathbb{R}^{X} \;\;\text{concave and}\;\; h\ge f\}$.

All were extracted from different textbooks or articles. They refer to the concave envelope of $f$.

Are they all equivalent?

I can see how they are related, but, for instance, for $g$ strictly concave with $g(x)\ge f^{***}(x)$, $f^{***}(x)=g(x)$ but what about $f^{*}(x)$? Why is continuity required in definition 2?

Comment: In finite dimensions, def 2 and def 1 are equivalent because all affine functions are continuous there.

Comment: Right! Concave functions are continuous as well, so implicitly in def 1 and def 3 there might be the hypothesis of X finite.

Comment: Another thing to note is that the pointwise infimum of affine functions is again concave and $f^*$ is a function which is concave and for which $f^*\geq f$. Or, more clearly, there is the inclusion $\{h(x):h\in\mathbb{R}^X\mbox{ affine and }h\geq f\}\subset \{h(x):h\in\mathbb{R}^X\mbox{ concave and }h\geq f\}$.

Comment: May I know where those definitions come from?

Answer (score 1):

Posed as it is posed, for general $X$ (hence possibly infinite dimensional) it is clear that there may exist linear unbounded functions, making the two definitions nonequivalent.

Note also that for general $X$ we may not even be sure the $\min$ exists in definition $3$.

Knowing what is $X$ (a generic set, a set endowed with a preference relation and maybe an order topology, a finite dimensional space,...) is fundamental for the question, since in total generality it is false.

Comment: I think you can consider X to be a subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, with $n$ finite. More generally, $X$ is a vector is a real topological vector space.